# How to make the def function work in a if statement?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I am new to python and i am making a text based adventure game, to make it more interesting instead of printing the questions normally i found a text effect shown here

```
import time
import sys

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.03)

delay_print("Hello World")
```

So i am trying to make this script work within an if statement. it works perfectly outside a if statement but the second i put it into a if statement the def stops working. VSC does not show an error but nothing happens

here is the script that does not work

```
choice = input("left or right? ")

if choice == ("left"):
    import time
import sys

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.03)
        delay_print("Left")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.    You don't even call ```delay_print```,  so you won't get any output.   And even if you do call ```delay_print```, you will will get an error along the lines of 'time.sleep' is not defined when choice != "left".

Comment: is there any way to fix this or, could you send me a code that does work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should put the import statements at the top of your script.
2. Define the `display_print` function outside the for loop and call it in the if statement. (There is no reason to define the function inside the if statement, you can just call it there.)

This should work:

```
import time
import sys

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.03)
    
choice = input("left or right? ")

if choice == "left":
    delay_print("Left")
```

Comment: Hey Ake, I just tried your code and it came back the same.

Comment: How exactly did you run the code?
You should:
Save the code in a Python file with a ".py" extension, for example, "script.py".
Open a command prompt or terminal on your computer.
Navigate to the directory where you saved the Python file.
Once you are in the correct directory, you can run the script by typing:
`python script.py`.

Comment: sorry Ake, I just checked it again and it now works thank you for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved your problem, you could accept the answer so other people are not spending time with this question anymore.